# Python pandas - Filter a data frame based on a pre-defined array

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter a data frame based on the contents of a pre-defined array.

I've looked up several examples on StackOverflow but simply get an empty output.

I'm not able to figure what is it I'm doing incorrectly. Could I please seek some guidance here?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

csv_path = 'history.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

pre_defined_arr = ["A/B", "C/D", "E/F", "U/Y", "R/E", "D/F"]
distinct_count_column_headers = ['Entity']

distinct_elements= pd.DataFrame(df.drop_duplicates().Entity.value_counts(),columns=distinct_count_column_headers)
filtered_data= distinct_elements[distinct_elements['Entity'].isin(pre_defined_arr)]    

print("Filtered data ... ")
print(filtered_data)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Filtered data ... 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Entity]
Index: []
```

Comment: Show us some data please...

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Appreciate your willingness to help. Managed to work out eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to that using `filter` function -> `.filter(items=pre_defined_arr )`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

csv_path = 'history.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

pre_defined_arr = ["A/B", "C/D", "E/F", "U/Y", "R/E", "D/F"]
distinct_count_column_headers = ['Entity']

distinct_elements_filtered= pd.DataFrame(df.drop_duplicates().Entity.value_counts().filter(items=pre_defined_arr),columns=distinct_count_column_headers)
```

It's strange that there's just one answer I bumped on that suggests `filter` function. Almost 9 out 10 out there talk about `.isin` function which didn't work in my case.